# Can I build my Vue project to run android WebView?

Tags: android, vue.js, mobile, android-webview

I have a Vue web project, which is used in my android apps.
The Apk consists native android code with my web apps in it as a .zip file

I want to try run my web app locally on WebView to test it, without having to build it in the Apk (because sometimes it has different behavior running with desktop browser)

Is it possible to do this?